# Get excepting object in AppDomain.UnhandledException handler

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling, unhandled-exception

I'm using an `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event handler to perform some logging when my application crashes due to an unhandled exception.

```
void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) {...}
```

I would like to be able to log the `typeof(object)` and various `object` fields/properties when the source of the unhandled exception is one of my custom object classes, but it seems that this information is not included either in the `UnhandledExceptionEventArgs` or as the `sender` object. I tried casting `sender` but understandably the `sender` is simply the `AppDomain` which has raised the exception.

Is there a way to retrieve this information from *within* this event handler? The only other thing I can think of is to use a static field to store a reference to an object each time that an object throws, but I think that requires that I have a static field for each type I want to do this for.

Note: I am aware that the `stack trace` may lead me to the source of the exception, however this does not allow me to log important *state* information regarding that object during the crash.

For example, if my stack trace from `e.ExceptionObject` is

```
Stack Trace: 
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at CustomLibrary.CustomObject.readCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   ...
```

I would like to be able to get a reference to the `NetworkStream` object, which will allow me to locate the associated `CustomObject` in a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using below code and see that exception is getting caught or not.. Also just check whether anywhere in your code your are rethrowing the exception like `throw ex`. If yes than it will eat up the stacktrace that you are looking for, try rethrowing using just `throw`.

```
  [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
    AppDomain currentDomain = default(AppDomain);
    currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    // Handler for unhandled exceptions.
    currentDomain.UnhandledException += GlobalUnhandledExceptionHandler;
    // Handler for exceptions in threads behind forms.
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException += GlobalThreadExceptionHandler;
    ...
    }

private static void GlobalUnhandledExceptionHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
   Exception ex = default(Exception);
   ex = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;
   ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
   log.Error(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
}


private static void GlobalThreadExceptionHandler(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
   Exception ex = default(Exception);
   ex = e.Exception;
   ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program)); //Log4NET
   log.Error(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Dev. I'm not having an issue catching the unhandled exceptions or producing a stack trace, all I want is to be able to get a reference to the object **from which** the original exception was thrown. I only ever rethrow exceptions using `throw;`.